# ImportError: cannot import name 'ASSOCIATION_PROXY' from 'sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am working on a small flask API using flask-admin and flask-sqlalchemy. The api runs well but whenever I install a new package I am faced with an error.

```
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brandoncreed/.local/share/virtualenvs/management-System-Wyc_ba1N/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/brandoncreed/Desktop/Brandon Coding Projects/management-System/src/app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from api.admin import setup_admin
  File "/Users/brandoncreed/Desktop/Brandon Coding Projects/management-System/src/api/admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
  File "/Users/brandoncreed/.local/share/virtualenvs/management-System-Wyc_ba1N/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .view import ModelView
  File "/Users/brandoncreed/.local/share/virtualenvs/management-System-Wyc_ba1N/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 18, in <module>
    from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.tools import is_relationship
  File "/Users/brandoncreed/.local/share/virtualenvs/management-System-Wyc_ba1N/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/tools.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import ASSOCIATION_PROXY
ImportError: cannot import name 'ASSOCIATION_PROXY' from 'sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy' (/Users/brandoncreed/.local/share/virtualenvs/management-System-Wyc_ba1N/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py)
```

I am not sure what is causing this but it seems there is a conflict between flask_admin and sqlalchemy after the new package is installed. I deleted the pipfile.lock in my virtual environment and ran pipenv install to see if the new file would work but it did not. I also tried uninstalling the new package to see if it would resolve the issue but the same error still persists. I am wondering if it was to do with updating either flask-admin or sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has been [fixed in Flask-Admin v1.6.1](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/doc/changelog.rst), which can be installed like this:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade flask-admin
```

Flask-Admin versions earler than v1.6.1 are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. The was an [issue](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/2305) for this specific problem. The recommended workaround was to install an earlier version of SQLALchemy, for example:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade 'sqlalchemy<2.0'
```

Comment: I appreciate the help with this! I did pipenv install 'sqlalchemy<2.0' and that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone ends in here like me, this was solved in flask-admin 1.6.1.
In Anaconda you can run `conda install flask-admin=1.6.1`.